# How to use implode?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a php code

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['invite'])) {
foreach($_POST['invite'] as $check) {
   echo implode($_POST['invite'], ',');
  }
}
```

Result is: sky,earth,universesky,earth,universe

Here result showing two times see after universe sky agian repeat, i want to show result only one.

Have any idea?

Comment: Make sure your original array doesn't contain a value of `universesky` then... clean up the array in the first place ([array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) perhaps?)

Comment: What purpose does the `foreach` serve? Get rid of it and just do `echo implode($_POST['invite'], ',');`

Comment: the title doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 5):

Just `echo implode($_POST['invite'], ',');` no need to use loop